# Executing excel formula using powershell taking too much time

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having below code which I using to calculate

```
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false  
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("C:\SLAFile.xlsx")
 
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$rows = $worksheet.range("D2").currentregion.rows.count

$STDSheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Add()
$STDSheet.Name = 'STD'

###### Copy Date #####
$worksheet.activate()
$lastRow1 = $worksheet.UsedRange.rows.count
$range1 = $worksheet.Range("B2:B$lastRow1")
$range1.copy()

$STDSheet.activate()
$lastRow2 = $STDSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
$range2 = $STDSheet.Range("A$($lastRow2)")
$STDSheet.Paste($range2)

###### Copy Date ######

###### Copy SYMM_ID ####

$worksheet.activate()
$lastRow3 = $worksheet.UsedRange.rows.count
$range3 = $worksheet.Range("A2:A$lastRow3")
$range3.copy()

$STDSheet.activate()
$lastRow4 = $STDSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
$range4 = $STDSheet.Range("C$($lastRow2)")
$STDSheet.Paste($range4)

###### Copy SYMM_ID ####
####### STD Column Header #######
$STDSheet.Cells(1,1) = 'Time (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,2) = 'DATE (TEXT FORMAT)'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,3) = 'SYMM_ID'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,4) = 'STD_RT'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,5) = 'IO/sec'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,6) = 'DATA/sec'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,7) = 'Block Size'
$STDSheet.Cells(1,8) = 'MIN RT/6h'

####### STD Column Header #######
##### STD Report Part ####
$count=73
for($j=2;$j -le $rows;$j++)
{
$k = $j-1
$STDSheet.range("B$j:B$j").formula = '=TEXT(A'+$j+',"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")'
$STDSheet.range("E$j:E$j").formula = '=IFERROR(SUMIFS(SLA!$G:$G,SLA!$C:$C,"SG_STG_*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,$B'+$j+',SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIFS(SLA!$H:$H,SLA!$C:$C,"SG_STG_*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,$B'+$j+',SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),0)'
$STDSheet.range("D$j:D$j").formula = '=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(SLA!$D:$D,SLA!$C:$C,"SG_STG_*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,SLA!B'+$j+',SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),"-")'
$STDSheet.range("F$j:F$j").formula = '=IFERROR(SUMIFS(SLA!$E:$E,SLA!$C:$C,"SG_STG_*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,$B'+$j+',SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIFS(SLA!$F:$F,SLA!$C:$C,"SG_STG_*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,$B'+$j+',SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),0)'
$STDSheet.range("G$j:G$j").formula = '=IFERROR($F'+$j+'*1024/$E'+$j+',"-")'
$STDSheet.range("H$j:H$j").formula = '=IF(COUNTIF($D'+$j+':$D'+$count+',">0")=72,MIN($D'+$j+':$D'+$count+'),"-")'
$STDSheet.range("I1:I1").formula = '="Nb Period with Min RT > "&5&"ms"'
$STDSheet.range("I$j:I$j").formula = '=IFS($H'+$j+'="-","NA",$H'+$j+'<=5,"OK",$H'+$k+'>5,"NOK CONT",1,"NOK START")'
$STDSheet.range("j1:j1").formula = '=COUNTIF($I:$I,"NOK START")'
```

The problem is, when I keep only **1000-2000** records in the input file, the code executes very quickly.
But the actual input file contains around **90k** records. when I execute that it takes too much time.

Please let me know is there anything wrong with the code? Is there any way to make the execution faster?

While trying I have broke the master excel into 1000 rows each and kept in separate files and tried to execute. but then also I am getting the same slowness issue

```
$GetExcels = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\xlfile\multiple'

foreach($EFile in $GetExcels)
{
}
```

Comment: SUMIFS,AVERAGEIFS, COUNTIF are very heavy formula and 90k referencing full columns will be very very slow.  The only thing you can do to help is limit the full column references to just the size of the dataset.

Comment: [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) makes manipulating Excel files a lot easier than using the COM object. If using that module doesn't allow you to manipulate 90k records in one go, maybe break the task up to make multiple spreadsheets and then combine them into one?

Comment: @ScottCraner: Thanks for your response. Can you provide some example on how to do it?